# How to zoom and pan multiple charts with livecharts library

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, pan, livecharts

I'm using beto-rodriguez's livecharts for WPF. I get data for charts from xml file and than i draw charts one above another, charts representing data have same number of spots on X axis and ZOOM and PAN are enabled with ch.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.X; and ch.Pan = PanningOptions.X;
My question is possible to zoom or pan one (doesnt matter which) of those charts and that all of them are zoomed or panned so that i have vertically aligned X axis of all of them? Basically if I zoom or pan on one chart all others should zoom and pan in same time and for same amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is create an event handler for the event "RangeChanged" on each graphs' axis

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Time" RangeChanged="Axis_RangeChanged" Separator="{x:Static lvc:DefaultAxes.CleanSeparator}" DisableAnimations="True" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```

In the event handler you then can extract the new min and max value for the axis and apply it to all the graphs you have on your page

```
private void Axis_RangeChanged(LiveCharts.Events.RangeChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //sync the graphs
        double min = ((Axis)eventArgs.Axis).MinValue;
        double max= ((Axis)eventArgs.Axis).MaxValue;

        this.lvcChart2.AxisX[0].MinValue = min;
        this.lvcChart2.AxisX[0].MaxValue = max;

        this.lvcChart.AxisX[0].MinValue = min;
        this.lvcChart.AxisX[0].MaxValue = max;

        //Repeat for as many graphs as you have
    }
```

There might be some other cool way by using commands and binding but this will at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the pan and zoom on X axis vertically.
Firstly I created a class which reads the xml and creates object which is prepared for livecharts library then I create charts dynamically and give every axis the name

```
            Axis axisX = new Axis();
            Axis axisY = new Axis();
            axisX.Name = "X";
            axisY.Name = "Y";
```

then create an event that is fired on range change like @Kevin Ross mentioned and in the method for that event loop through all axis and checking name of the axis and then change minValue and maxValue like this:

```
        void axisX_RangeChanged(LiveCharts.Events.RangeChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        double min = ((Axis)eventArgs.Axis).MinValue;
        double max = ((Axis)eventArgs.Axis).MaxValue;


        int p = 0;
        string name;
        foreach (Axis CartChart in FindVisualChildren<Axis>(TestGrid))
        {
            // do something with CartChart here
            name = CartChart.Name;
            if (name == "Y")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (name == "X")
            {
                CartChart.MinValue = min;
                CartChart.MaxValue = max;
            }

            p++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Unless you are adding graphs at runtime I would cache the charts in a list in your code so you are not having to walk the visual tree each time your loop is called. If it is called a lot then it might become a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Yes I am adding graphs at run time because I dont know number of graphs in the begining. I know that .add()method can lead to bottleneck but I think that there is no other way.

Comment: Yes but once you have added them I would cache them so you are not walking the tree on every loop. If you add/remove them during the lifetime of the form then just invalidate the cache and it will load them again.

Comment: Ouu...You are right, I will change that in program It should be faster :D