# Livecharts: Zoom to a specific region in CartesianChart

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I am using `LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart` and load it with a `GLineSeries`. What I want to do, is to zoom to specific region of the X-Axis. Is it somehow possible in `LiveCharts`?
I could not find any method `CartesianChart` doing that.

Comment: I guess you visited already [this link](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Zooming%20and%20panning) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zoom and pan multiple charts with livecharts library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479495/how-to-zoom-and-pan-multiple-charts-with-livecharts-library)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do that. I think the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` mentioned in the comments will perhaps work, too. But instead of changing the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` directly, I found another way. You can bind the `CartesianChart` to  a `BindingAssistant`. There you can set the `From` and `To` Value. Then the `CartesianChart` is automatically zoomed to the region.
The code would look like this:

```
var assistant = new BindingAssistant
{
    From = ZoomDateStart.Ticks,
    To = ZoomDateEnd.Ticks
};

cartesianChart1.AxisX[0].SetBinding(Axis.MinValueProperty,
    new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("From"), Source = assistant, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
cartesianChart1.AxisX[0].SetBinding(Axis.MaxValueProperty,
    new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("To"), Source = assistant, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

The advantage of using this method is that now the chart can also be made scrollable. For more info: [Example](https://github.com/Live-Charts/GearedExamples/tree/master/WinForms/FinancialSeries)